# Run a script with a script within a script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a script (say A) that will run a script (Say B) in multiple
directories. Script B runs a script (say C) in a set of sub directories. While I
wrote and successfully executed Script B and C, combining them and writing
Script A seems a bit too difficult for me.

An example  of B is

```sh
MainDir="/home/kkk/mmm/dir" 
create_stack="${MainDir}/run/create_stack_and_find_seam.rb"
# cd into the working main directory where all the subdirs are present  
for fil_no in $@  
do
  cd ${MainDir}/${fil_no}
  pwd
  # the working script              
  echo ${fil_no}
  ${create_stack} ${fil_no}
done
# Go back to the original starting directory
cd $OLDPWD
```

The script above (Script B) runs the Ruby Script "create_stack_and_find_seam.rb"
in a set of directories enlisted fil_no.
Now I have several directories with different subdirectories listed "fil_no" at
various levels.
So I now need to execute Script B in all the directories which, in Turn will run
"create_stack_and_find_seam.rb" ( that is Script C) in all the different
subdiretories.

Comment: I would make 'Script B's 'MainDir' a parameter and then have 'Script A' call a selection of different instances of 'Script B'. For example Script A would run 'ScriptB.sh /home/kkk/mmm/dir' then 'ScriptB.sh /home/kkk/mmm/differntdir' and so on. This might help http://doitwithlinux.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/slightly-more-advanced-guide-to-shell.html

Comment: Please can you provide some clarity to the question? Is ruby script to recursively search directories and do processing from $MainDir? Does it do that now if you run it separately? Some idea of the directory structure may also help.

Comment: Hi @suspectus - Yes ruby script to recursively search directories and do processing from $MainDir. No I do not run it separately. Script B does it for me. The fil_no is a txt file have the list of subdirectories to run the Ruby script. The directories are - /home/kkk/mmm/dir main directory &  in there subdirectories 2,3..7 exist. Each of subdirectory (2,3,..) have further subdirectories. The ruby script 'create_stack_and_find_seam.rb' needs to run in each of the sub-to-sub directories.

Comment: @suspectus - Does this answer your question- do let me know. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, if we change the 'MainDir' in Script B to a parameter as shown below

```
MainDir=$1
```

We can then write script A as:

```
#!/bin/bash
ScriptB.sh /home/first/directory
ScriptB.sh /home/second/directory
```

Of course this would mean changing the `${MainDir}/run/create_stack_and_find_seam.rb` and `cd ${MainDir}/${fil_no}` section. If these are only ever in one place then removing the MainDir and adding a new variable would help